# Is not using return value in Python bad practice/dangerous?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that only sometimes returns values. Below a simplified example.

```
def return_something(bool):
    if bool:
        return "Something"
    else:
        print("Hello ")
```

I figured that I could also rewrite the function as such:

```
def return_something():
    print("Hello ")
    return "Something"
```

As I only sometimes need the return value and when I need it the rest of the function may execute normally. Now I would call the function in two ways:

```
return_something()
string = return_something()
```

My question: When using the second design I don't use the returned value in the first function call. Is this considered bad practice and or dangerous?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I changed the phrasing to make it more clear.

Comment: Usually if you have a function, you want it to perform one task, and its explicitly clear what that task is by the function name. If that task is to always return the sum of two values, it does that and nothing else. This way your code is very easy to understand, and you won't get instances where you call the function, expect a return value but it prints instead.